# Comment entry screen shows even though "Allow Comments" is unchecked

Tags: theme-development, comments

On my single.php and index.php I'm including the comment entry routine with this code...

```
<?php if(get_option('allow_comments_posts')){comments_template();} ?>
```

However, when the specific post being viewed in single.php has "Allow Comments" unchecked, I don't want the comment template to appear.

I was under the impression that the comments_template() routine automatically managed this, but apparently I need to wrap it or pass a paramater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember main purpose of [`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) is to load template and specific logic should be handled inside that template.

Snippet from Twenty Ten `comments.php`:

```
if ( ! comments_open() ) :
?>
    <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; // end ! comments_open() ?>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me there. Apparently, something is amiss with my $post variable or scope. Even though the current post I'm looking at has "allow comments" unchecked, comments_open() is returning true. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what's happening. I have a "Related Articles" listing just before the comments_template() call. The $post->ID is getting reset to the last post in the link list for those articles. Should I redeclare $post inside comments.php? If so, $post = ?

Comment: @Scott B try [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after your related section

Comment: BINGO! That did it. Thanks Rarst. As always, you're right on the money :)